# Black screen on first boot of ubuntu mate

Tags: display, ubuntu

I am trying to install Ubuntu mate on my rpi2. But so far, I am only getting a black screen (I don't even see a the colorful splash screen)
I installed NOOBS on my MicroSD card to ensure that the card is not faulty, and NOOBS booted up instantly.
I cross checked the md5 hash from Ubuntu mate's website, so my download was not corrupted.
And since I am using HDMI to DVI-D cable, I un-commented the line `hdmi-force-output=1` in `config.txt` (There was no need to do this step while installing NOOBS)
I also removed all the peripheral devices (only HDMI & power cable are there at boot)
And also the green light blinks for a few minutes, and now only red light is on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uncomment `#hdmi_safe=1`

This should work. I have seen similar reports, and suspect there is some difference in the Ubuntu Mate.

If this gets you a display, you can explore the modes available.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Although the display resolution was very low. But I fixed that in `config.txt` I am guessing it's a bug in mate?

Comment: Working solution also on Ubuntu Mate 20.04